# How to remove Nextcord in order to continue with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever I try to run my code with discord.py, it shows me an error saying "DistributionWarning: discord.py is installed which is incompatible with nextcord. Please remove this library by using `pip3 uninstall discord.py`
warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)" but the thing is I don't want to uninstall discord.py I want to uninstall Nextcord.

Even tho i wrote pip3 uninstall Nextcord it did not work.

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Have you tried `pip uninstall nextcord`? (small `n`, not CAPS `N`)

Comment: Are you sure you're doing it in the correct Python environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

##### Linux/macOS

```
python3 -m pip uninstall -U nextcord
```

##### Windows

```
py -3 -m pip uninstall -U nextcord
```